# Invalid Operands of types char and const char[2] to binary operator

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, char

im really confused as why i keep getting this error.  I am trying to subtract two chars like "c"-"a"=2 based on their ascii values but i keep hitting errors no matter what I do (ive been trying different things for over an hour). Please help me or clarify what im doing that is incorrect.

```
char vigenere_letter (char plain_text, char key_letter) {
    int rotation;
    string new_alphabet;
    rotation = plain_text - "a";
    new_alphabet = rotate_left(rotation, alphabet);
}
```

Comment: `"a"` is a string, not a char. You want `'a'`

Comment: Did you mean to write `rotation = plain_text - 'a';` instead?

Comment: thanks a ton guys!  quite embarassed about this one!

Answer (score 0):

You meant to write `rotation = plain_text - 'a';`

`"a"` is a `char*` (a "string", multiple characters), while `'a'` is a single character (a `char`)

Comment: As the error message says, `"a"` is a `const char [2]`, not a `char *`.

Comment: You are welcome, as you are new here, you may want to read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work